# how do i add a custom animate duration for every time i call this function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

  var el = $("#box");

  animate(el,300,function(){

  });


});


function animate(el,leftVal,callback){

el.animate({
    left : leftVal
},{
    duration : 2000,
    queue    : false,
    easing   : "swing",
    complete : function(){
        //alert("finished");
        if(callback){
            callback();
        }
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Im trying to pass a unique animate speed for every time i use the function, here i only know how to use it at 2000

Comment: How are you planning on passing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `duration` parameter to your function:

```
function animate(el, leftVal, callback, duration) {
```

Then call the parameter in the duration part of the function:

```
{
    duration: duration,
    ...
}
```

When you're calling the function, define the last parameter (which is now the duration):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var el = $("#box");
    animate(el, 300, function() {
    },1000); // 1 second duration (1000 milliseconds)
});
```

Comment: @DanMan: No problem. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it by clicking the white checkmark on the left side of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, im new to stack so bear with me. Thanks again.